# Contingency table and confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, contingency

Let me describe my problem by a simplified example

I have a contingency table

```
datatable<-array(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,dim=c(3,2))
datatable<-cbind(datatable,rowSums(datatable))
datatable<-rbind(datatable,colSums(datatable))
```

here, m=3,n=2 This is a (m+1)x(n+1)=4x3 table. Now, i want a new mxn array, where the ij'th entrance is a confidence interval (a list of size 2 if you will) for the estimate datatable[i,j]. Below is a function that computes an interval for the estimate datatable[i,j] from the arguments a<-datatable[i,j] and b<-datatable[i,n+1]

```
CIfunction<-function(a,b) c(-1,1)+a*b
```

I hope it is not too messy, i couldn't think of an easier example.

How do i create such a table in a elegant way? In the real example, this is a function that should take arbitrary contingency tables and return the corresponding CI table.

I already found a way, using double loop over i resp. j, but it really smells like something that could be done in an elegant way using mapply/outer or thelike.

Comment: First line is missing a closing parenthesis. A better explanation would help. If you have a for-loop that does what you expect , you should edit you question to include it. (That "confidence interval function" seems pretty arbitrary and it unclear what arguments you intend to pass to it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for your comments and answers. I had abit of trouble generalizing the (elegant) method provided by ilir to arbitrary CI functions. I ended up just doing the double loop  mentioned above. My solution to the above problem would be something like

```
CItable<-function(datatable,CIfunction)
{
 m<-dim(datatable)[1]-1
 n<-dim(datatable)[2]-1

 CItable<-array(NA,dim=c(m,2*n))
 for(i in 1:m)
   {
    for(j in 1:n)
     {
      tempint<-CIfunction(datatable[i,j],datatable[i,n+1])
      CItable[i,2*j]<-tempint[2]
      CItable[i,2*j-1]<-tempint[1]
     }

   }
return(CItable)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below involves some trickery because it relies on how R recycles vectors ([under what circumstances does R recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555651/under-what-circumstances-does-r-recycle)). `array` and `matrix` objects are just folded vectors (stored column-wise). It's not hard to come up with tricks like this once you understand the behavior

```
datatable <- array (1:6, dim=c(3,2))
datatable <-cbind(datatable,rowSums(datatable))
datatable <-rbind(datatable,colSums(datatable))

# last column recycled as necessary
lower <- -datatable[1:3, 1:2] * datatable[1:3, 3]  
upper <- -lower
CIlist <- list(lower, upper)
```

I do suggest, however, that you store `datatable` without the row and column totals and compute them only on print.