# R: Combining lapply and left_join to conditionally merge dataframes

Tags: r, if-statement, left-join, lapply

I'm hoping someone out there might be able to help me get to the root of a frustrating problem I've been having with my code in R. I have a list consisting of dataframes, and I want to left join each element on one of two OTHER dataframes (call them A and B). Which of these secondary dataframes to join on depends on the element's position in the list. For my purposes, I'd like every odd element to be left-joined to A, and every even element to be left-joined to B.

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(Num = c("1","2"), Let = c("a","b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
A <- data.frame(Let = c("a","b"), Col = c("Yellow","Red"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
B <- data.frame(Let = c("a","b"), Col = c("Green","Blue"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
LIST <- list(DF, DF)
```

So far, I've tried to do this in two different ways. The first approach involved an if-else statement. If I apply such a statement to assign an integer value based on position, I obtain the expected result. Similarly, when I do away
with the if-else statement and simply perform a series of left-joins on the list
elements, everything works as expected.

```
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x, {ifelse((x %% 2)==0, y[[x]] <- 1, y[[x]] <- 2)}, y = LIST)
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x, {left_join(y[[x]], A, by = c("Let"))}, y = LIST)
```

Where I run into problems is when I attempt to combine the if-else statement and the left join. In particular, I end up with a list consisting of lists, each
of which retains only the first column of the original corresponding dataframe.

```
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x, y) {ifelse((x %% 2)==0, left_join(y[[x]], A, by = c("Let")), left_join(y[[x]], B, by = c("Let")))}, y = LIST)
```

Here is the output I would LIKE to obtain:

```
[[1]]
  Let Num    Col
1   a   1 Yellow
2   b   2    Red

[[2]]
  Let Num   Col
1   a   1 Green
2   b   2  Blue
```

I'm certain there's an absurdly simple solution to the problem. Can anyone see it?

Thanks in advance!
Matthew

**P.S.:** I also attempted a second approach, applying subsetting rather than an if-else statement. Again, however, I run into problems. The first line below works as expected, but the second returns an error, as though R doesn't recognize the list indices:

```
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x, y) {left_join(y[[x > 0]], A, by = c("Let"))}, y = LIST)
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x, y) {left_join(y[[x == 1]], A, by = c("Let"))}, y = LIST)

Error in y[[x == 1]] : attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include your expected output. The first two `lapply` statements throw errors.

Comment: Hi Maurits Evers - thank you for your incredibly prompt reply! I have edited the question just as you requested. The first two statements threw errors because I absentmindedly forgot to call dplyr.

Comment: As an aside, instead of saying repeatedly that you don't want `stringsAsFactors`, say `library(hellno)` lol

Comment: install.packages("hellno") throws an error :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

Use [`base::mapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html) to return a list of data frames which were conditionally merged. Here, I supply two inputs:

1. [`seq.along( along.with = LIST )`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/seq) to obtain the number of elements in `LIST`; and
2. `LIST` itself.

The `FUN` argument is an anonymous function that takes in two inputs - `i` and `j` - and tests whether the current element in `LIST` is even or odd numbered prior to performing a [left-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) using [base::merge()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html).

If the [result of the modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160930/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd) for the i<sup>th</sup> element in `seq.along( along.with = LIST )` is equal to zero, then left-join `B` onto the j<sup>th</sup> element in `LIST`; if it does not equal zero, then perform the left-join `A` onto the j<sup>th</sup> element in `LIST`.

```
# load data
DF <- data.frame(Num = c("1","2"), Let = c("a","b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
A <- data.frame(Let = c("a","b"), Col = c("Yellow","Red"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
B <- data.frame(Let = c("a","b"), Col = c("Green","Blue"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
LIST <- list(DF, DF)

# goal: left join all odd elements in LIST[[j]]
#       to `A` and all even elements to `B`
merged.list <- 
  mapply( FUN = function( i, j )
          if( i %% 2 == 0 ){
            merge( x = j
                   , y = B
                   , by = "Let"
                   , all.x = TRUE )
          } else{
            merge( x = j
                   , y = A
                   , by = "Let"
                   , all.x = TRUE )
          }
        , seq_along( along.with = LIST )
        , LIST
        , SIMPLIFY = FALSE )

# view results
merged.list
# [[1]]
# Let Num    Col
# 1   a   1 Yellow
# 2   b   2    Red
# 
# [[2]]
# Let Num   Col
# 1   a   1 Green
# 2   b   2  Blue

# end of script #
```

## Tidyverse approach

The results are replicated below using functions from the [purrr](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) and [dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) packages.

```
library( dplyr )
library( purrr )

merged.list <-
  map2( .x = seq_along( along.with = LIST )
        , .y = LIST
        , .f = function( i, j )
          if( i %% 2 == 0 ){
            left_join( x = j
                       , y = B
                       , by = "Let" )
          } else{
            left_join( x = j
                       , y = A
                       , by = "Let" )
          })

# view results
merged.list
# [[1]]
# Num Let    Col
# 1   1   a Yellow
# 2   2   b    Red
# 
# [[2]]
# Num Let   Col
# 1   1   a Green
# 2   2   b  Blue

# end of script #
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply to my query! I think this may actually solve my problem :D - although I still need to play around with the code a bit to verify. For some silly reason, I had it in my head that one can only use mapply if he or she has two lists/vectors of equal length.

Comment: @M.Stargardter no problem! In this case, the lengths of `LIST` and `seq.along( LIST )` are equal. However, for cases where this is not true, the unequal input will be recycled. For more on that, see [under what circumstances does R recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555651/under-what-circumstances-does-r-recycle) and [How to define multiple variables with lapply?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48598720/7954106).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your issue.

The following solution is based on a reproduction of the output of `lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x, y) {left_join(y[[x > 0]], A, by = c("Let"))}, y = LIST)` from your postscript. Note that the other `lapply` lines throw errors.

```
library(tidyverse);
map(list(A, B), function(x) left_join(DF, x))
#Joining, by = "Let"
#Joining, by = "Let"
#[[1]]
#  Num Let    Col
#1   1   a Yellow
#2   2   b    Red
#
#[[2]]
#  Num Let   Col
#1   1   a Green
#2   2   b  Blue
```

We use `purrr:map` with `dplyr::left_join` to join `A` and `B` with `DF`.

---

The same can be achieved in base R using `Map` and `merge`:

```
mapply(function(x) merge(DF, x, by = "Let"), list(A, B), SIMPLIFY = F)
#[[1]]
#  Let Num    Col
#1   a   1 Yellow
#2   b   2    Red
#
#[[2]]
#  Let Num   Col
#1   a   1 Green
#2   b   2  Blue
```

Comment: Hi! This certainly does the trick ... however, the issue would be to extend this approach to a list containing an arbitrarily large number of elements. Thus, if I had a list consisting of 100 items, how would I go about merging the 1st, 3rd, 5th, ... 99th items to dataframe A, and the 2nd, 4th, 6th ... 100th items to dataframe B?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that MauritsEvers has already answered your question but I thought I would address the obvious errors in R syntax and programming logic. Focus on the first lapply-call:

```
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x, {ifelse((x %% 2)==0, y[[x]] <- 1, y[[x]] <- 2)}, y = LIST)
```

First and perhaps trivial is the missing closing `)` argument list in the first `lapply`-action. Next and more fundamental is the incorrect use of `ifelse` as a programming construct. The `ifelse` function is not designed for serial tests of data-objects. It is only designed to be applied along a single vector. The `if(.){.}else{.}`-function probably should have been used in that `lapply` call if serial choices were to be made.

However, (and now trying to implement the first paragraph rather than continue correecting code) I think it would be much simpler to use logical indexing (with R's implicit recycling process) on the `LIST`-object rather than any looping process. (This is *not* a tidyverse solution.) This code would segment the LIST into "odd" and "even" components:

```
  oddList <- LIST[ c(TRUE,FALSE) ]  # implicit seq-along by virtue of recycling
  evenList <- LIST[ c(FALSE,TRUE) ]
```

We could use that type of results to make two one-liners that would accomplish your stated goals. I made the LIST-object four wide rather than two wide.

```
Abig <- Reduce( function(x,y) {merge(x,y,by="Let")}, LIST, init=A)
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "Let") :
  column names ‘Num.x’, ‘Num.y’ are duplicated in the result
Bbig <- Reduce( function(x,y) {merge(x,y,by="Let")}, LIST, init=B)
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "Let") :
  column names ‘Num.x’, ‘Num.y’ are duplicated in the result
```

That is only a warning and here you can see what it was warning about:

```
> Abig
  Let    Col Num.x Num.y Num.x Num.y
1   a Yellow     1     1     1     1
2   b    Red     2     2     2     2
```

If you need those duplicated column names labeled uniquely (and I thin that would be a good idea), then:

```
names(Abig)[ grep("Num", names(Abig)) ] <- 
                    paste0("Num.", seq_along( grep("Num", names(Abig)) ) )
Abig
  Let    Col Num.1 Num.2 Num.3 Num.4
1   a Yellow     1     1     1     1
2   b    Red     2     2     2     2
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to prepare such a detailed response! I particularly appreciate your note regarding the appropriateness of the if-else statement. Others observed this as well, so I will definitely exercise more caution in applying this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is quite similar to `mapply` based solution already posted here by (@MauritsEvers &  @aspiringurbandatascientist) but it usages a different approach to `join` data.frames. The `dplyr::left_join` has been used to fit the purpose.

```
library(dplyr)
# Using mapply and left_join
mapply(function(x,y){
  if(y %% 2 == 1){
    left_join(x, A, by="Let")
  }else {
    left_join(x, B, by="Let")
  }
}, LIST, seq_along(LIST), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# [[1]]
#   Num Let    Col
# 1   1   a Yellow
# 2   2   b    Red
# 
# [[2]]
#   Num Let   Col
# 1   1   a Green
# 2   2   b  Blue
```

Comment: It's always helpful to see multiple approaches to solving a problem - thanks so much for taking the time to respond to my question!

Comment: @M.Stargardter You are always welcome. I appreciate question with enough data to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked a bit your example data for clarity

**data**

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Num1 = c("1","2"), Let = c("a","b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF2 <- data.frame(Num2 = c("3","4"), Let = c("a","b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF3 <- data.frame(Num3 = c("5","6"), Let = c("a","b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF4 <- data.frame(Num4 = c("7","8"), Let = c("a","b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
A <- data.frame(Let = c("a","b"), Col = c("Yellow","Red"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
B <- data.frame(Let = c("a","b"), Col = c("Green","Blue"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
LIST <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4)
```

**Solution**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
LIST_odd  <- LIST[as.logical(seq_along(LIST)%%2)]
LIST_even <- LIST[!as.logical(seq_along(LIST)%%2)]
merge_odd <- reduce(LIST_odd,left_join,.init=A) 
#   Let    Col Num1 Num3
# 1   a Yellow    1    5
# 2   b    Red    2    6

merge_even <- reduce(LIST_even,left_join,.init=B)
#   Let   Col Num2 Num4
# 1   a Green    3    7
# 2   b  Blue    4    8
```

If you don't want to use `purrr` those give the same result with only `dplyr` and `base`:

```
Reduce(left_join,LIST_odd,A)
Reduce(left_join,LIST_even,B)
```

Or 100% base:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all.x=TRUE),LIST_odd,A)
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all.x=TRUE),LIST_even,B)
```